# crear un boton de megusta como twitter

Tags: php, pdo

hola una pregunta com puedo hacer un boton de megusta como lo tiene Twitter
este es mi script

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=7MedQZ36mR;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC");
$sql->execute();
while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $_SESSION['avatar'] = $result['avatar'];

  echo '<li class="rv b agz">
  <a href="'.$result['usuario'].'">  <img
      class="bos vb yb aff"
      src="img/avatar/'.$_SESSION['avatar'].'"></a>
    <div class="rw">
      <div class="bpb">
        <small class="acx axc">'.$result['time_date_post'].'</small>
        <h6><a href="'.$userid.'">'.$result['usuario'].'</a></h6>
      </div>

      <p>';
      $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
      $result['cuerpo'] = str_replace("\n", "<br/>",$result['cuerpo']);
  if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $result['cuerpo'], $url)) {
    echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a id="link" href='.$url[0].'>'.$url[0].'</a>', $result['cuerpo']);
  }
  else {

    echo $result['cuerpo'];
  }

      echo '</p>';
      if ($result['image'] == "") {

      }else {
        echo '<div rel="shadowbox" class="boy" data-grid="images">
        <img style="display: inline-block;width: 468px;height: 269px!important;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-right: 0px;vertical-align: bottom;border-radius: 2%;border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);" data-action="zoom" src="'.$result['image'].'">
        </div>';

      }
      if ($result['video'] == ""){

      }else{
          echo '
          <div class="boy" data-grid="images">
             <!--VIDEO PLAYER-->
             <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

             <iframe style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-right: 0px;vertical-align: bottom;border-radius: 2%;border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;" class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$result['video'].'" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
              <!--END VIDEO PLAYER-->
          </div>

          ';
      }
echo "<span><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>";
    echo "</div>
  </li>";
}
?>
```

y esta es mi tabla de los post en la base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` varchar(2500) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `cuerpo` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(3500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(3500) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_date_post` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  `mg_cont`int(11)NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

bien ahora les comentare mi problema con el que me tope al tratar de hacerlo y fue como hago que sea auto incrementable pensé en usar un UPDATE pero también me tope que si uso un update ya deberia haber un valor dentro de la variable "mg_cont" sino este no actualizaría o me lanzaría un error, por lo que me quede sin ideas alguno tiene una idea para mejorar mi codigo? ademas me gustaria que el usuario una vez dio megusta el boton solo le permita quitar ese megusta y el conteo baje descuerdo a ese unico usuario que dio ese megusta 
un ejemlo

usuario1 da un megusta al post del usuario2

tabla post>mg_cont>+1

pero luego:

usuario1 quita su megusta del post del usuario

tabla post>mg_cont>-1

y se habilite de nuevo para volver a dar un megusta

si añaden ejemplos me ayudarían mucho

Comment: Porque no usas `DEFAULT 0`?

Comment: @alanfcm y como hago que se incremente? y baje dependiendo de si el usuario dio el MG o lo quito?

Comment: Deberás vincular el `onclick` del botón de *MG* a un llamado AJAX a tu archivo PHP, el cual deberá hacer un `UPDATE` de dicha columna, que idealmente ya debería empezar en `0` para que de este modo sea `UPDATE tabla SET MG := MG + 1` y entonces por cada vez que el usuario de click se sumará 1 al valor actual

Comment: Y para que el usuario retire ese megusta? osea para que no siga incrementando

Comment: @Max, desde mi punto de vista, el registro de los "me gusta" de los usuarios deberías guardarlos en una tabla de detalle (postID, userID, date). ¿Por que así? Es la forma más fácil de saber: ¿quien voto que y cuando?. Ahora que pasa ¿si ya no le gusta mas?, podrías borrar el registro o agregar una columna para esto. ¿como se cuantos votos tiene un post? Basta con hacer un `count` a esta tabla indicando el `postID`. Saludos!

Comment: @Marcos me podrías pasar un ejemplo con lo que me comentas?

Comment: @Max, lo que Marcos describe tiene que ver con diseño de bases de datos.
Te recomiendo que consultes sobre el tema http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?cap=003 y sobre normalización, como ejemplo, imagina que tienes una tabla de clientes y otra de prestamos, donde cada cliente puede tener uno o mas prestamos y cada prestamo puede tener uno o mas pagos, entonces cómo y dónde guardas los pagos? En una tabla de pagos, que contenga el id del prestamo en cuestion, el monto y la fecha. Saludos

Comment: PD: En el caso de likes, la transitiva incluye también el id del usuario porque es una relación de muchos a muchos. Es decir, un usuario puede gustar de más de una cosa y cada cosa puede ser gustada por más de un usuario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te recomiendo los siguientes cambios en tu base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cuerpo` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(3500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(3500) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_date_post` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  FOREIGN KEY(userID) references users(id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `usuario` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `me_gusta` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postID` int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(userID, postID),
        FOREIGN KEY(userID) references users(id) on delete cascade,
        FOREIGN KEY(postID) references post(id) on delete cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

En primer lugar, sacar los usuarios en una tabla externa (No sé si ya lo tenías, pero en caso de tenerlo, te recomiendo que añadas una Foreing Key a la tabla Usuarios desde la tabla Posts, esto le dará integridad a la base de datos y te permitirá que un usuario cree varios posts.

Por otro lado, para el tema de los me gusta te recomiendo crearte una tabla externa donde cada vez que un usuario le de me gusta a un post, este quede almacenado en la tabla "me_gusta", para sacar los me gusta de un post puedes hacerlo mediante la siguiente query:

`SELECT COUNT(1) as total FROM me_gusta WHERE postID=<id del post>`

De manera que si un post no tiene "me gusta" saldrá 0. Si un usuario elimina el me gusta pues lo eliminas de la tabla con un delele.
Además, te he añadido un delete on cascade en los me gusta para que si un post se elimina, se eliminen los me gusta asociados a él. Lo mismo ocurre con los usuarios.

Finalmente el tema de que un usuario sólo pueda dale me gusta una única vez se controla poniendo como primary key el idUser y el idPost, como son la clave primaria, no pueden repetirse y por tanto un usuario puede votar una única vez.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, lo edito.